# Firebase not sending emails?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't get `Firebase` to send verification emails, anyone with the same issue?
I've created an account, enabled Email/Password, and added users.

[image]

However, when I go to the `Users` tab in `Authentication`, chooses a user and presses `Reset password`, Firebase tells me, that the email is send, however I never receive it?

[image]

[image]

I've tried with multiple different emails (gmail, hotmail etc) and looked through spam etc, however I never receive the email. What am I doing wrong? Some setting somewhere I need to tick-off? Rookie question, I know, but frustrating. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same problem with an user, he didn't receive any email with his work email address from Firebase magic link authentication.
I'm still using Firebase as provider but I think to integrate with sendgrid soon.

[image: Firebase support answer]

Comment: Thanks! I just set up Sendgrid, and now the emails are arriving as they should. Wired ... Thanks for the hint!